# MySQL Adapter Fill Exception

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a MySQL query I'm running from C#. I use the `MySqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`. However I am getting the following exception:

> MySql.Data.Types.MySqlConversionException: Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime

I can't really modify the query (it's loaded from an external source). And I'm hoping I don't have to manually fill the data table. Anyone had this before?

I should also add I have tried adding `allow zero datetime=no` to the connection string with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you made a mistake with your addition to the connection string! It should be:

```
Allow Zero Datetime = true
```

Comment: Modified your example since the OP doesn't want to allow zero dates.

Comment: I shall accept this answer only because I tried Allow Zero Datetime = true and it worked! I'm fine with zero dates I just can't modify the actual query.

Comment: Not allowing zero dates is likely what is causing the exception though. Setting Zero Datetimes to true means an object is returned for illegal values rather than an exception.

Comment: Well my goal is to export the data that is returned, so having an invalid field throw out the rest of the data was a problem.